# _ZN4half5_eLutE undefined for OpenCV 3.3.0 build

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using C++ to build an OpenCV project on NetBeans 8.0 using openCV 3.3.0 on Ubuntu 16.10 LTS.

The compilation is error and warning free.  However, the compilation fails, in the link stage, as _ZN4half5_eLutE is seen as undefined.  The following shows the link process and the results.

```
cd '/home/peter/NetBeansProjects/ApplyModelToSet'

/usr/bin/make -f Makefile CONF=Debug


"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf


make[1]: Entering directory '/home/peter/NetBeansProjects/ApplyModelToSet'


"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/applymodeltoset


make[2]: Entering directory '/home/peter/NetBeansProjects/ApplyModelToSet'


mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux


g++ -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/applymodeltoset applymodeltoset.o build/Debug
/GNU-Linux/_ext/73c876dd/colour.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/_ext/73c876dd
/correlation.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/_ext/73c876dd/fft.o build/Debug/GNU-
Linux/_ext/73c876dd/wirth.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/_ext/73c876dd/xmlReader.o
 build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o -L../../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu 
-L../../xerces-c-3.1.4/src/.libs -L../../Downloads/opencv-3.3.0/build/lib 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.a -lxerces-c -lopencv_calib3d 
-lopencv_calib3d_pch_dephelp -lopencv_core -lopencv_core_pch_dephelp 
-lopencv_dnn -lopencv_dnn_pch_dephelp -lopencv_features2d 
-lopencv_features2d_pch_dephelp -lopencv_flann -lopencv_flann_pch_dephelp 
-lopencv_highgui -lopencv_highgui_pch_dephelp -lopencv_imgcodecs 
-lopencv_imgcodecs_pch_dephelp -lopencv_imgproc 
-lopencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp -lopencv_ml -lopencv_ml_pch_dephelp 
-lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_objdetect_pch_dephelp 
-lopencv_perf_calib3d_pch_dephelp -lopencv_perf_core_pch_dephelp 
-lopencv_perf_dnn_pch_dephelp -lopencv_perf_features2d_pch_dephelp 
-lopencv_perf_imgcodecs_pch_dephelp -lopencv_perf_imgproc_pch_dephelp 
-lopencv_perf_objdetect_pch_dephelp -lopencv_perf_photo_pch_dephelp 
-lopencv_perf_stitching_pch_dephelp -lopencv_perf_superres_pch_dephelp 
-lopencv_perf_video_pch_dephelp -lopencv_perf_videoio_pch_dephelp 
-lopencv_photo -lopencv_photo_pch_dephelp -lopencv_shape 
-lopencv_shape_pch_dephelp -lopencv_stitching 
-lopencv_stitching_pch_dephelp -lopencv_superres 
-lopencv_superres_pch_dephelp -lopencv_test_calib3d_pch_dephelp 
-lopencv_test_core_pch_dephelp -lopencv_test_dnn_pch_dephelp 
-lopencv_test_features2d_pch_dephelp -lopencv_test_flann_pch_dephelp 
-lopencv_test_highgui_pch_dephelp -lopencv_test_imgcodecs_pch_dephelp 
-lopencv_test_imgproc_pch_dephelp -lopencv_test_ml_pch_dephelp 
-lopencv_test_objdetect_pch_dephelp -lopencv_test_photo_pch_dephelp 
-lopencv_test_shape_pch_dephelp -lopencv_test_stitching_pch_dephelp 
-lopencv_test_superres_pch_dephelp -lopencv_test_video_pch_dephelp 
-lopencv_test_videoio_pch_dephelp -lopencv_test_videostab_pch_dephelp 
-lopencv_ts -lopencv_ts_pch_dephelp -lopencv_video 
-lopencv_video_pch_dephelp -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_videoio_pch_dephelp 
-lopencv_videostab -lopencv_videostab_pch_dephelp -ljpeg -lz -lIlmImf 
-lopencv_flann  -pthread -lopencv_flann



/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_exr.cpp.o): undefined reference to symbol '_ZN4half5_eLutE'


//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so.12: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line


collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status


nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:102: recipe for target 'dist/Debug/GNU-    Linux/applymodeltoset' failed


make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/applymodeltoset] Error 1


make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/peter/NetBeansProjects/ApplyModelToSet'


nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:97: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed


make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2


make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/peter/NetBeansProjects/ApplyModelToSet'


nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed


make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

I understand that there are several similar strings defined in libopencv_flann.a but it is included.

Comment: I notice `-lopencv_flann` appears before `-lopencv_imgcodecs`. That could be a problem if the latter is dependent on the former. Then again, the former also appears twice more later on.

Comment: I tried putting -lopencv_flann last but still got the same error.  Thanks,

Comment: Can you compile using command line: `g++ *.cpp -o test 'pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs' -lpthread` ? Just to make sure you're including all `.so` files.

Comment: I got     g++: error: pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs: No such file or directory    Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.  _ZN4half5_eLutE is not part of OpenCV 3.3.  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu contains libraries from an earlier version of OpenCV.  When I made ../../Downloads/opencv-3.3.0/build/lib the first search directory, the problem went away because _ZN4half5_eLutE was no longer necessary.